# .Net 5 change DbContext in controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a design where I have one "master" database and multiple "client" databases. When I get a request I lookup in the master database and setup the connection to the right client database.

I'm now trying to design the same in .net 5, where I setup the masterDB in StartUps ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddDbContext<Models.DataContext.MasterContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer("Name=MasterDB"));
```

I then on the request lookup in the MasterDB as the first thing in every controllers methods and find the connectionString for the clientDB.

**But how do I then set it up at that point in time? While also not having to think about disposal of the connection, like when it's passed in using dependency injection, it's handled.**

Any advice to do things slightly different are also encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your MasterContext into a service that provides connection string lookups for your "client" databases (probably with caching).  Then use that when resolving and configuring your "client" DbContext.

Something like this:

```
    class ClientDatabaseService
    {
        MasterDbContext db;
        IHttpContextAccessor context;

        static Dictionary<string, string> cache = null;
        public ClientDatabaseService(MasterDbContext db, IHttpContextAccessor context)
        {
            this.db = db;
            this.context = context;
            if (cache == null) RefreshCache();
        }
        public void RefreshCache()
        {
            cache = db.Clients.Select(c => new { c.ClientID, c.ConnectionString }).ToDictionary(c => c.ClientID, c => c.ConnectionString);
        }
        public string GetClientConnectionString()
        {
            var clientId = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("ClientID").Value;
            
            return cache[clientId];
        }

    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<MasterDbContext>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<ClientDatabaseService>();

        services.AddDbContext<ClientDbContext>((services, options) =>
        {
            var constrService = services.GetRequiredService<ClientDatabaseService>();
            var constr = constrService.GetClientConnectionString();
            options.UseSqlServer(constr, o => o.UseRelationalNulls());

        });


    }
```